# Why doesn't `transfer` to owner change its balance?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, ethereumjs

I am building a contract to transfer ether to the contract's owner and test it via hardhat. I found that the owner's balance doesn't change after the transfer. below is the contract code:

```
contract Test is ERC20,Ownable {

    constructor(uint256 price) ERC20("Test", "OMN") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000);
    }

    function testTransfer() public payable {
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

In the unit test, I have code:

```
async function deployFixture() {
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const Test = await ethers.getContractFactory('Test');

    const [_, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const contract = await Omniverse.deploy(1);
    return { contract, owner,addr2 };
  }

it('test transfer', async () => {
    const { contract, owner, addr2 } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);
    const addr2Contract = await contract.connect(addr2);
    const ownerWalletBalance = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)));
    await addr2Contract.testTransfer({ value: 100 });
    const ownerWalletBalanceAfter = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)));
    
    console.log('ownerWalletBalance', ownerWalletBalance, ownerWalletBalanceAfter);
  });
```

The output from above unit test is:

```
ownerWalletBalance 9999.995976379376 9999.995976379376
```

The `testTransfer` transfers the value from `msg` to the contract's owner. But the balance printed out in the log shows there are exactly the same before and after the method is called. I can't figure out what wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The value you sent in this line is in wei.

```
await addr2Contract.testTransfer({ value: 100 });
```

100 wei is equal to 0,0000000000000001 eth. It is possible that the two values are different, but your output needs to have more numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

The balances of `owner` and `addr2` are getting changed, you're passing the `value` as `100` which is very small in terms of 18-decimals (as **Wei**), if you send by parsing it using `ethers.parseEther('100')`, then the change in balances are quite noticeable as it'll transfer **100 Ether** instead of **100 Wei**, like this:

```
it('test transfer', async () => {

        const { contract, owner, addr2 } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);

        const addr2Contract = await contract.connect(addr2); 

        const ownerWalletBalance = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)));

        const addr2WalletBalance = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(addr2.address)));

        await addr2Contract.testTransfer({ value: ethers.parseEther('100') })

        const ownerWalletBalanceAfter = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)));

        const addr2WalletBalanceAfter = parseFloat(ethers.formatEther(await ethers.provider.getBalance(addr2.address)));

        console.log('ownerWalletBalance', ownerWalletBalance, ownerWalletBalanceAfter);

        console.log('addr2WalletBalance', addr2WalletBalance, addr2WalletBalanceAfter);

});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to wait a few seconds before you query the balance. It turns out that when you do `await addr2Contract.testTransfer({ value: 100 });` the script moves to the next line as soon as the transaction is inserted into the blockchain.

But for you to see a change in the owner's Balance you would need to wait until the transaction is validated.  Because you are using the simulated environment of Hardhat it may seem to you that the validation runs instantly, but it may not actually have been the case.

Comment: in brief: Your script might be querying the balance before the validation/confirmation of the transfer